# Realm incorrect thread access crash

Tags: ios, multithreading, asynchronous, realm

I am late to this party and newbie to Realm

I have created a signleton class having following method to write but it crashes at times because incorrect thread access

Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

```
 func save<T:Object>(_ realmObject:T) {
    let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: ".realm", qos: .background)
    backgroundQueue.async {
        let realm = try! Realm()
       try! realm.write {
            realm.add(realmObject)

        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for asking this question! The incorrect thread access exception is a result of the Realm object being passed through a thread boundary. I recommend reading the documentation on [Passing Instances Across Threads](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#passing-instances-across-threads) and [this blog post](https://realm.io/news/obj-c-swift-2-2-thread-safe-reference-sort-properties-relationships/) (specifically the section on thread confinement).

In order to avoid that exception, you'll need to change your code to:

```
func save<T:Object>(_ realmObject:T) {
    let realmObjectRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: realmObject)
    let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: ".realm", qos: .background)
    backgroundQueue.async {
        guard let realmObject = realm.resolve(realmObjectRef) else {
            return // although proper error handling should happen
        }

        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(realmObject)
        }
    }
}
```

The `ThreadSafeReference` object, [documented here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/2.4.2/api/Classes/ThreadSafeReference.html) provides you with a *thread safe reference* for a given Realm object that can be passed through a thread boundary and then resolved back to a thread-confined object once you're safely inside a different thread. I hope this helps and let me know if you need anything else. Cheers!